# Simple PMOSFET 12 Volt Motor Control

Tags: mosfet, dc-motor

I tried making a simple control circuit the other day, but was a bit of a dud. Hoping that someone can help point out where I went wrong.

I was hoping that disconnecting the switch would draw the MOSFET to ground, with a VGS of -12V, then connecting it to the 12V would bump the VGS to 0V, shutting off the circuit.

Without the control circuit, the motor runs fine. Turning the switch off does not turn on the MOSFET. Is my resistor incorrectly sized? Am I just totally off base? Should I settle for an NMOSFET and low side switching?

Thanks!

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fqhuA0.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: Double check the pinout of your MOSFET and your wiring.  Try a second FET in case the first is damaged.  There's nothing wrong with your schematic, it should work, though an NFET in the low side would also be OK.

Comment: Does your schematic show the actual part number for your transistor? Could you provide a link to the transistor's data sheet, please?

Comment: I've triple checked the wiring. I'm suspecting I may have a busted MOSFET. However, most of what I read says that a broken MOSFET will conduct and not shut off.

All my voltages and grounds appear to in fact be 12V and ground also. I'm going to just hook up the GND directly to the gate and see if that does anything. If not, I'm thinking I'll be replacing the MOSFET.

Elliot, yes, I am using the IRF9Z34.

Data sheet: https://www.mouser.com/datasheet/2/196/irf9z34npbf-1228318.pdf